# Adding custom fields to Google Ads Conversion Tag in GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

A client gave me a conversion event code using gtag / global site tag...

```
gtag('event', 'conversion', 
{ 'send_to': 'AW-XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX', 
    'customField1': 'submitted', 
    'customField2': 'something',
 });
```

...which I am trying to implement via Google Tag Manager. However, I don't see a way to add custom fields (customField1, customField2) via the Google Conversion tag in GTM.

Am I missing something? Or using the wrong tag?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this could be useful: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets